# Running a command inside a folder which has a path with spaces

Tags: cmd

I want to run a gulp command inside a folder `C:\Projects\Workspace - ProjectX\webapps\` so what I'm doing is I cd into this this folder from command prompt and I run this command :

```
gulp prepare-source -m prod
```

but I get this error :

```
'C:\Projects\Workspace' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a known issue in `gulp-protractor`.  Please check the following links for status update on the issue:

https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor/issues/64

It seems it has been fixed for Windows 7.  Check if you are running the latest version of gulp.

https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor/pull/112

Answer (score -1):

You need to install gulp globally if you want to run it anywhere.

```
npm install gulp -g
```

Comment: that folder has the a `gulp.cmd` in it, and this problem is only when I have a path containing a space